# Babel types transform - adds space around operators. How to bypass?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, transformation, codemod

I have a line of code I am trying to make with a babel transform.

This, `const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>("")`

However, when I run my transform to insert this code, the `<brackets>` are both given extra space around them. So I get `useState < string > ("")`...

I feel like this is probably intentional code formatting. But for this particular area, I would like it to not do that. I don't want the extra space around the operators just for this part of my code..  How can I make that to happen?

Here's my transform/configuration

```js
types.variableDeclaration("const", [
        types.variableDeclarator(
            types.arrayPattern([
                types.identifier("firstName"),
                types.identifier("setFirstName")
            ]),
            types.binaryExpression(
                ">",
                types.binaryExpression(
                    "<",
                    types.identifier("useState"),
                    types.identifier("string")
                ),
                types.parenthesizedExpression(types.stringLiteral(""))
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

"@babel/core": "^7.12.13",

"@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.12.13",

I could only find information on how to add the extra spacing, but not remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make a type annotation, you need to make a type annotation AST node, not a `binaryExpression` and `parenthesizedExpression` and such. AST nodes have specific meanings and what you are constructing is a syntactic description rather than a semantic description, hence the weirdness.

If you don't know the AST node types that you need, it is generally a good idea to run Babel's parser on the code you want to produce, because they you can see the node types that you need.

In your case you need something like this:

```
const callNode = types.callExpression(
  types.identifier("useState"),
  [types.stringLiteral("")]
);
callNode.typeParameters = types.tsTypeParameterInstantiation([
  types.tsStringKeyword()
]);

const declNode = types.variableDeclaration("const", [
  types.variableDeclarator(
    types.arrayPattern([
        types.identifier("firstName"),
        types.identifier("setFirstName")
    ]),
    callNode,
  )
]);
```

All that said, constructing all of this by hand can be pretty tough, so depending on your needs, I'd consider doing it with `template`, e.g.

```
const declNode = template.statement({ plugins: ["typescript"] }).ast`
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>();
`;
```

Comment: Thanks. The call expression was what I needed to use. I wish there was a better way to set the type parameters. It's odd, the callExpression shows up when I actually parse it from babel, but in AST Explorer -it's a binaryExpression. https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/e8258b5130695ee0e38bec4c23a21cea/bf1e4e4476c386e2fb97b1431f76915ae35af512

Comment: You probably didn't tell AST Explorer to parse the file as TS. The code you pasted ins valid JavaScript _also_, but it has different behavior. This is one of the few cases where TS is not strictly a superset of JS, but in fact changes its parsing behavior. https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/e8258b5130695ee0e38bec4c23a21cea/ec4e89489535d873db2c3739b502b74e346e99c2

Comment: All I can do is select babel-parser, or typescript parser, no?

Comment: @SeanMC The gear icon next to `babel-parser` lets you choose what parser plugins to enable. `typescript` is one of them, just make sure to disable `flow` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, literally just found that and was about to update my comment, but you beat me to it. Thanks again!